# Google login in php

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

I am trying to login with google in my project.Login page is working fine but when i am trying to fetch data, i am getting this error.Thank you in advance .

I am running my php code on wampserver. and i am coding the page on visual studio.you can see my code.

//this is my code google_login.php

```
<?php 
    require_once('config.php');
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) 
    {
        $token = $gClient->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $token;
    }
    $oAuth = new Google_Service_Oauth2($gClient);
    $userData = $oAuth->userinfo_v2_me->get();
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($userData);
?>

//this is my config.php
<?php 
session_start();
require_once "GoogleAPI/vendor/autoload.php";
$gClient = new Google_Client();
$gClient->setClientId("1049012749051-01hv5pmer43duvcfa7q9872j1jtmp6bi.apps.googleusercontent.com");
$gClient->setClientSecret("LzTnjxrHg5Kl0h7z2MJ0-9Ru");
$gClient->setApplicationName("Anytime Learn");
$gClient->setRedirectUri("http://localhost/atl/google_login.php");
$gClient->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
?>
```

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL
>   error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
>   certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in
>   C:\wamp64\www\atl\GoogleAPI\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php
>   on line 187 ( ! ) GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error
>   60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
>   (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in
>   C:\wamp64\www\atl\GoogleAPI\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php
>   on line 187 Call Stack
>
> ## Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0021  406776  {main}( )   ...\google_login.php:0
>
> 2 0.0174  424824  Google_Client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode(
>   ) ...\google_login.php:5
>   3 0.0320  519024  Google\Auth\OAuth2->fetchAuthToken(
>   ) ...\Client.php:191
>   4 0.0334  597056  Google\Auth\HttpHandler\Guzzle6HttpHandler->__invoke(
>   ) ...\OAuth2.php:492 5    0.0334  597056  GuzzleHttp\Client->send(
>   ) ...\Guzzle6HttpHandler.php:34
>   6 0.1267  636424  GuzzleHttp\Promise\RejectedPromise->wait(
>   ) ...\Client.php:106

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the return is expecting a https url and not http://localhost/atl/google_login.php. You have to make your local work on https.

you need to download the curl recognised certificates: https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

Save the cert.pem file and point to it in your php.ini, you're looking for CURLOPT_CAINFO